# Android Espresso failed to install instrumentation

Tags: android, adb, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

When I want to execute Android espresso test via gradle I will get an error that instumentation can not be installed

```
10:52:09.094 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':myModule:connectedAndroidTest'.
10:52:10.204 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] DeviceConnector 'GT-P3100 - 4.2.2': installing myApp.apk
10:52:34.889 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] DeviceConnector 'GT-P3100 - 4.2.2': installing instrumentation.apk
10:53:18.152 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Starting 0 tests on GT-P3100 - 4.2.2
10:53:18.152 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Project] Tests on GT-P3100 - 4.2.2 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
10:53:18.396 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] DeviceConnector 'GT-P3100 - 4.2.2': uninstalling de.my.app.test
10:53:20.267 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] DeviceConnector 'GT-P3100 - 4.2.2': uninstalling de.my.app
```

Comment: The logs on the device might give some clues. Can you post the logs from the time of the crash?

Comment: Is this specific to one device? Does your app use the NDK?

Comment: (@2) 
- No my app does not use NDK
- I figured out that it happens on all devices < Android 4.3
- When I use a phone with Android 4.3 or 4.4 I won't get this error

Comment: I/dalvikvm( 5505): Could not find method com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.ExposedInstrumentationApi.execStartActivity, referenced from method com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentation.execStartActivity`

Comment: W/dalvikvm( 5505): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1378: Lcom/google/android/apps/common/testing/testrunner/ExposedInstrumentationApi;.execStartActivity (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/IBinder;Landroid/os/IBinder;Landroid/app/Activity;Landroid/content/Intent;I)Landroid/app/Instrumentation$ActivityResult;

Comment: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource( 5505): Cannot load class. Make sure it is in your apk. Class name: 'android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2'. Message: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2

Comment: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource( 5505): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2
...
W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource( 5505):  at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:366)
...
W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource( 5505): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2
W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource( 5505):  at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:114)

Comment: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource( 5505): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2" on path: /system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/de.my.myapp.test-1.apk:/data/app/de.my.myapp-1.apk